# Android Remote Video View does not adapt to other user's device orientation

Tags: quickblox

On the new Android video chat sdk sample, if the remote device's orientation is opposite your device, the main video view draws with AspectFill and the video is stretched.

I noticed that iOS sample has a config of AspectFit for the video view.  Is there a similar setting for the Android SDK?